# Node.js: running setInterval while certain variable is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, setinterval

I have a setInterval function and isRunning variable.
How do I stop setInterval when isRunning gets set to false?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comments inline:

```
var isRunning = true; // Define it outside so that can be accessed inside setInterval

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // Your code here


    // Check if variable is false, then clear interval
    if (isRunning == false) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 100);
```